# VS Code Jupyter Extension: Remote notebook not starting

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to connect to a remote Jupyter notebook using the VS Code Jupyter extension.

Using <kbd>CMD + Shift + P</kbd> -> `Jupyter: Enter the URL of local/remote Jupyter notebook` brings up an input field, where I enter the address of the notebook. Afterwards an input field asking for the token is shown. When I enter the token and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens.

I tried to connect using VS Code for MacOS and Linux Mint. Using a notebook hosted on `localhost:8888` and well an notebook hosted on a different computer within my home network `192.168.0.11:8888`. Both ways do not work.

I can access the Jupyter notebooks via browser.

When I start VS Code per command line with a Python environment, that has `jupyter` installed, I am also able to run a notebook (purely) within VS Code. If I do not start VS Code within a Python environment with `jupyter` installed, I am not able to run any notebooks (but this seems to be an know issue).

How do I solve this issue (connect to a remote notebook)?

Is someone able to connect to a remote notebook? (If yes, how?)

Answer (score 0):

Use following command:

`jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8080 --allow-root`

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it would appear that you got the token incorrect. When I chose the option to enter the Url of a remote server and got the token wrong, the only indication things weren't working was the fact that I couldn't execute any Python code. And, when I used that same Url in a browser, I got a web UI that asked me to enter a token. Once I found and entered a valid token, I got their nice little UI for working in notebooks.

As for my experience, I just got it working in VsCode a few moments ago: I have a .ipynb file open in VsCode, it's switched to being pointed at my remote Jupyter Server, and I can execute code against it and get output.

## Overview of my setup

### Prerequisites

1. I have VsCode setup with the Python, Pylance, Jupyter, Jupyter Keymap, and Jupyter Notebook Renderers extensions (I also have OpenJDK 11 ([Microsoft's distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download)) installed so I can run PySpark code locally when I want to). I did these as part of my initial forays into Python and then using Jupyter Notebooks.

   - While I've been able to use Jupyter Notebooks and have autocomplete/Intellisense working against my local machine, I don't know enough to say which extensions are required for this, nor if there's some setup I did as part of that which is critical for this remote setup to work.
2. I'm on a Windows 10 box and have WSL2 setup with a Ubuntu image and Docker is installed and setup within it.

### The steps

1. Install a docker image that has Spark, Python, PySpark, and Jupyter all setup for you: `docker run -d --name jspark -p 8888:8888 jupyter/pyspark-notebook`
2. Get the auth token: `docker exec -it jspark jupyter server list`
3. Get the IP address of **eth0**: `ip addr`
4. Using the output of the previous 2 steps, build the final URL that you can use from the host (Windows) OS to connect to the Jupyter server.
5. Prove it works by navigating to it in a browser.
6. Over in VsCode, use that same URL as the location of the remote Jupyter Server.
7. Get autocomplete/Intellisense working by locally installing "pyspark": `python -m pip install pyspark`.

   - Before I ran that, I didn't have Intellisense in my remote-connected notebook; Intellisense worked immediately afterwards. From that, I gather that the "Jupyter" extension does not have a way to use the remote server to provide that info (Notebooks [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65527025/530545) use Jupyter instead of Pylance for Intellisense.).

If everything goes as expected, VsCode will "think" for a bit while it tests the connection, and then you'll see that "play" button show up to the left of your Python cell(s).

I used this code to prove it was working:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.json("/usr/local/spark/examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
df.show()
```

And now I can move on to improving the experience, since I have a known working baseline.

Answer (score -2):

The problem I encountered is as follows

```
command 'jupyter.selectExistingNotebook' not found
```

I installed the Jupyter extension on vscode.
Follow the instructions:
Remote Jupyter kernel on Server / Docker

Try this to connect to a remote Jupyter kernel running on a server, or inside Docker container:

Start a remote Jupyter Notebook or headless KernelGateway

Find the token in the output of the Jupyter server logs: http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html

Then in VS Code: ctrl+shift+p

Jupyter: Enter the url of local/remote Jupyter Notebook

I only installed docker and run the container.