# intellisense vscode not showing parameters nor documentation when hovering above with mouse

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm trying to migrate my entire workflow from eclipse and jupyter notebook all over to VS Code. I installed the python extension, which should come with Intellisense, but it only worse partly. I get suggestions after typing a period, but don't get any information on parameters nor documentation when hovering over with my mouse. Thank you so much for your help and have a wonderful new year!

P.S If anyone has any experience with using anaconda environments with VS Code, that would be greatly appreciated as well as I running into some problems with it recognizing the libraries.

[image: Image of completion suggestions]

[image: Image of no parameters nor documentation]

Also you can see here that when I manually activate Intellisense, it doesn't recognize that it's in a method.

[image]

Sorry for the long string of edits, but I discovered that when typing print in a regular python file, it works, but not in a jupyter notebook file. Also, it still doesn't work for numpy. Thanks for the help everyone.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the shortcut key "`Ctrl`+`Space`" to open the suggested options:

[image]

In addition, it is recommended that you use the extension "[Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)", which works better with the extension "Python".

[image]

Update:

Currently in VSCode, the "IntelliSense" document content is provided by the Python language service, which is mainly for Python files (".py" files call this function), while in Jupyter, the "IntelliSense" used by the ".ipynb" file comes from the extension "Jupyter". You could refer to the content of this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4307#issuecomment-755440329) to use VS code insiders, and its notebook editor has better intellisense.

In VS code insiders:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll definitely look into that. Just wondering, shouldn't parameters and documentation show up in the stock form of IntelliSense that comes with the python extension. Thanks!

Comment: @albert chen -I tested the code "_import numpy as np_  _np.array()_", and the results showed that the effect of "IntelliSense" in the ".py" file and ".ipynb" file is the same. (These options are displayed at "np.array", and shortcut keys are needed at "np.array()".)

Comment: Thanks, do you know where I can find these shortcut keys. I was under the impression that all you had to do was hover your mouse over to get the documentation as shown in the demos online. Thanks.

Comment: @albert chen -You could click "_F1_" and enter "_Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)_", or refer to this document: [Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Have a great rest of your day!

Comment: I was hoping to get documentation in the jupyter notebook cells like the ones I am able to get with the regular python file. Is this possible? If not, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @albert chen -I updated my answer and you could refer to it.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is just what I've been looking for!